# Not able to upload file with size more than 5 MB, issue with html input file size

Tags: php, html

I am working on PHP and making a script to upload video, I have set the max file size on php.ini to 20MB but still when I select a video of size more than 5MB, the form does not even get posted while it does with file size less than 5MB.

I updated these values in php.ini

```
post_max_size = 20M
upload_max_filesize = 500M
```

And below is my form :

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    echo "hello";
}

?>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action = "">
<input type="file" name = "file" data-max-size="100048">
<input type="submit" name = "submit">
</form>
```

Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: no errors, it does not post .. like it just displays on the title bar the spinning wheel for a while and comes back with nothing at all, without entering the post submit condition mentioned above in my php code.. and does enter the condition when the file size is less than 5MB

Comment: Did you restart Apache?

Comment: @liquidflo I also restarted apache and can see in phpinfo that max upload size is 20 MB but cant even accept more than 5MB

Answer (score 2):

Try this, remove the data-max-size attribute from the file-input field and use the HTML hidden field instead:

```
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="6000000" />
```

Comment: Can you please explain the relation between the value of an HTML data-* attribute and Http POST size limit?

Comment: This also not working,., it return back 1 before the input form.

Comment: This is client validation. Any help on the server side.